# Leave empty space at beginning of flex-box instead of the end

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have boxes that are arranged in columns, top-to-bottom, left-to-right, like this:

```css
.container {
  height: 400px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.box {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: blue;
  margin: 8px;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  font-size: 24pt;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="box">1</div>
  <div class="box">2</div>
  <div class="box">3</div>
  <div class="box">4</div>
  <div class="box">5</div>
  <div class="box">6</div>
  <div class="box">7</div>
  <div class="box">8</div>
  <div class="box">9</div>
  <div class="box">10</div>
</div>
```

There is some empty space below the 10th box since there is room for two more boxes in its column.

Instead of having this space at the end, is it possible to make this space at the beginning instead? Here's an image of what I mean:

[image: four columns of numbers with space at beginning]

If it's possible to achieve this without changing the markup that would be preferable, but if necessary it's OK to reverse the order of the items or add some extra markup. It should work correctly with an arbitrary number of boxes.

Comment: is it possible to reverse the order of divs ? they begin from 10 ... 1 , if so i have a solution

Comment: @John That's acceptable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well , i just reversed your div order ,
added a `direction:rtl` , and reversed the column order. Taddaa

```css
.container {
  height: 400px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column-reverse;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
direction:rtl;
}

.box {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: blue;
  margin: 8px;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  font-size: 24pt;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="box">10</div>
  <div class="box">9</div>
  <div class="box">8</div>
  <div class="box">7</div>
  <div class="box">6</div>
  <div class="box">5</div>
  <div class="box">4</div>
  <div class="box">3</div>
  <div class="box">2</div>
  <div class="box">1</div>
</div>
```